# Translation request: “never stop fighting for what matters most”

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, sentence-translation

Alternatively, the phrase **always fight for what matters most**. It’s for an inscription on the back of a necklace, and I have somewhat of a character limit (35 characters, I was told) so I’m trying to keep it brief. That said, I’m not worried if it’s a rough translation or imperfect. I tried my hand at it from the little I know so far and anything would be better than my clumsy attempt, which was pieced together through a lot of Google searches of other translations: *Dignum est pro plurimum oportet proeliari.*

Very new Latin student here by the way, and I don’t know if this is allowed (I didn’t see anything about it in the rules though I could have missed something) but I would love any recommendations for where to look for good learning resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say:

> *Ne destiteris ad quod maxime oportet niti.*

Although in English, we often use *never* with negative imperatives, I believe it's less common in Latin.

According to *[Latin Grammar](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/imperative)* by Allen and Greenough, the usually way for expressing prohibitions are as follows:

> **450.** Prohibition is regularly expressed in classic prose (1) by nōlī with the infinitive, (2) by cavē with the present subjunctive, or (3)
> by nē with the perfect subjunctive.

Of these choices, I chose the latter option, i.e., *ne* with the perfect subjunctive: *Ne destiteris*.

This form of expression was also used by Cicero:

> ***Ne destiteris** ad me quicquid tibi in mentem venerit scribere.* (Cic. Att. 9.9.1)
>
> **Don't stop** writing to me whatever comes to mind.

Cicero also used combination of *ad … niti*, which means to struggle of fight for something:

> *Quod quidem ni ita haberet, ut animi immortales essent, haud optimi
> cujusque animus maxime **ad** immortalitatem gloriae **niteretur***. (Cicero,
> *De Senectute*, ch. 23 §82)
>
> And, indeed, were it not true that the soul is immortal, it would not
> be the case that it is ever the souls of the best men that **strive most
> for immortal glory**.

Comment: Very thorough and detailed answer. I never got around to thanking you for your excellent response. Could I trouble you for a more accurate English translation of your chosen wording? I have to confess to a very rudimentary understanding of Latin, which is only one reason your response is invaluable.

Comment: @Percandri - I believe what you requested is a pretty accurate translation of the Latin. *Ne destiteris … niti* means "Don't stop fighting", and *ad quod maxime oportet* means "for what is most necessary."